# Connection refused, Twisted

Tags: python-3.x, wamp, twisted, wamp-server

Я новочок в Twisted. Скопировал пример с сайта **crossbatio.com**:

Код:

```
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import Application
app = Application()
@app.register('com.example.square')
def square():
    x = 2
    print("square() called with {}".format(x * x))
    return f'This is a test of com.example.square {x * x}'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("ws://127.0.0.1:9000", "realm1")
```

Пытаюсь запустить сервис. Он валится с ошибкой:

> twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused
>   by other side: 61: Connection refused.

Если вместо порта **9000** поставить порт **8080**, получаю эту же ошибку.

Если убрать порт вообще и оставить строку:

```
app.run("ws://127.0.0.1", "realm1")
```

Получаю вот такие сообщения:

> 2018-04-22T11:48:13+0300 failing WebSocket opening handshake
>   ('WebSocket connection upgrade failed (200 - OK)')
>   2018-04-22T11:48:13+0300 dropping connection to peer tcp4:127.0.0.1:80
>   with abort=True: WebSocket connection upgrade failed (200 - OK)

Насколько понимаю, сервис стартовал с ошибкой (могу и ошибиться).

Собственно, вопрос вот какой. Как стартовать сервис по заданному порту?
Может быть кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Подкажите, как решить, пожалуйста.

Работаю в **PyCharm**, **Python 3.6.1**

Comment: вы wamp router пытались запустить сначала? https://asciinema.org/a/6ufqm00z2xmdb3xdnrrzf4es7

Comment: Да, я пытался по этому видео создать клон. Но ничего не получилось. Создается каталог и он пустой. Видимо, видео устарело.

Comment: если у вас  git clone команда не работает (или по любой другой причине не может wamp router запустить), то отдельный вопрос специально об этом задайте.

Comment: У меня все работает. crossbar-starter (https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar-starter) заархивирован на гитхабе. И склонировать его попросту нет возможности.

Comment: *"У меня все работает"* -- вы хотите сказать, что запустили wamp router? На каком порту?

Comment: Я подразумевал git clone. Wamp router я так и не смог установить в силу причин, описанных постом выше.

Comment: как я уже сказал, если не можете запустить, задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом. Если у вас конкретный шаг сложности вызывает, то лучше о самом шаге спросить (к примеру, "как запустить X docker контейнер на Y операционной системе"). Для контекста можно упомянуть, что вы хотите это знать, чтобы запусить wamp router, чтобы hello-world wamp application попробовать.